# How to write a simple Python Qt dialog on ROS Service?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to write a ROS Service that receives a Question and then shows a Qt Pop-up Dialog with the Question and a yes or no Button. The service should return the Answer as a Boolean.
I have it with wx but since it is depreciated in ROS, I want to use Qt now.
This is how it looked like with wx:

> ```
>     rospy.init_node('dialog_server')
> ```

```
    s = rospy.Service('dialog', Dialog, self.handle_dialog)
    rospy.spin()
    def handle_dialog(self, req):
        ex = wx.App()
        dial = wx.MessageDialog(None, req.message, 'Question',
                        wx.YES_NO | wx.ICON_QUESTION)
        ret = dial.ShowModal()
        if ret == wx.ID_YES:
                answer = True
        else:
                answer = False
        return DialogResponse(answer)
```

I tried simply replacing wx with the equivalent qt (like wx.MessageDialog -> QtGui.QMessageBox.question) but it's not working because ros is another Thread. Error: "It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread".
I am not familiar with Qt, rqt [python_qt_binding](http://www.ros.org/wiki/python_qt_binding) and plug-ins at all.

What do I need to achieve this?
Do I have to use Slots and Signals between GUI and ROS, or even write it as a plug-in? How should it look like?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69268/how-to-write-a-simple-python-qt-dialog-on-ros-service?/) by [msieber](https://answers.ros.org/users/3823/msieber/) on ROS Answers with karma: 181 on 2013-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS does *NOT* deprecates `wx` (, which is technically impossible because `wx` is externally hosted from ROS). ROS does so for some particular `wx-based` toolssuite [rx](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rx). That said you are free to continue using your own `wx`-based program. Advantage of doing so especially in your case would be that you don't have to rewrite anything. If you decide to continue using `wx`, you can look at the [source of rx tools](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rx).

For the particular error you mention about, I can't tell why it happens without looking at your `Qt` code.

And yes, if you choose to write in `Qt`, using its standard architecture like `slot`-`signal` is a good idea. If you extend it to `rqt` plugin, you get more benefits [as described](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt#Advantage_of_rqt_framework). [This tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt/Tutorials/Create%20your%20new%20rqt%20plugin) has a link to sample source of rqt plugin.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2